# How to write description document for JSON file?

Tags: json

I want to write a description document for my JSON files. I used to write it for database. It has ER Diagram and Data Dictionary. But when it comes to JSON file, are there any diagrams that can be used to describe JSON file that can be read easily?

Comment: Have you read http://www.json.org/fatfree.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/. For a json string like this,

```
{
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York"
  },
  "phoneNumber": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

It produces an output like,

[image: Sample json visualization for the above]